# Exception Handling with pointer

Tags: c++, exception

**how to handle the exception caused in this case using try-catch block. please help . thanks**

```
double **pDblArray = 0;
pDblArray = new double *[5000000];

for(int i=0; i<5000000; i++)


{
pDblArray [i] = new double [5000000];

}

cout << "Completed Allocated" << endl;
```

Comment: Fix it in what way? Other than using `new` and `delete` when you don't have to what's wrong with it. Use `std::vector<std::vector<double>>` and **boooooom** all that does away.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you say fix, what do you mean?

Comment: What's wrong is that you're trying to allocate nearly 200TB.

Comment: _how to fix this code using Exception handling_ No way from the information you give here! But trying to allocate `double *[5000000]` might be a stupid idea!

Comment: @EdS. You're just jealous 'cause his Timex Sinclair has all that memory!

Comment: Regarding down votes: Even not formulated well - the question is: how to manage a bad_alloc in the inner loop?

Comment: 182 terabytes of memory may be beyond even what the timex can allocate.

Comment: @DieterLücking So what would be the problem then to put a `try/catch` block there?!? No, that question is terrible (close voted).

Comment: The correct answer here is the one which tells you not to attempt to allocate ~190TB of memory (doesn't exist yet).  It just ain't gonna work.  You'll need to rethink your design.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I don't know the name of the particular exception for memory allocation overrun.  Look that up.

```
double **pDblArray = 0;
pDblArray = new double *[5000000];

try
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5000000; i++)  
    {
        pDblArray [i] = new double [5000000];

    }
}
catch (std::bad_alloc const &e)
{
    cout << "Boom! " << endl;
}
```

Comment: The exception is `std::bad_alloc` and `catch()` is wrong.

Comment: `try { /* ... */ } catch(){ /* ... */ } else // ...` Won't even compile! I have no idea, why this answer was accepted (panic accept maybe?)?!?

Comment: Ha, I guess you can't delete an accepted answer.   I tried to clean it up a bit at least...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have enough memory:

```
try {
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> vec(5000000, std::vector<double>(5000000));
    // …
} catch (std::bad_alloc const& e) {
    // …
}
```

Comment: I'm sure it's not as he's getting a `bad_alloc` long before.  As the code sample is not complete I'm just going to assume he's cleaning that memory up correctly and deal with the issue at hand.

Comment: @EdS., right, edited.